# curl xput windows Couldn't read data from file

Tags: json, curl, solr, cmd

I am using cURL in windows using command propmpt. When I am executing this command:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/schema/feature-store" --data-binary "@/path/myFeatures.json" -H "Content-type:application/json"
```

I am getting following error:

> ```
> Warning: Couldn't read data from file "/path/myFeatures.json", this makes an
> Warning: empty POST.
> ```

I have updated the file permissions and file is also present at the specific path.

What can be the possible solutions?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the path is correct? Have you tried using a relative path instead? An absolute path? Have you tried using backslashes instead of forward slashes? Do you include a drive letter in the path?

Comment: I know this Q is about Windows, but since it pops on Google, I'd like to leave a note here. I had this issue on Ubuntu as I installed curl using *snap* without thinking much. Apparently it runs in an isolated environment by default, so it is just easier to install it with a package manager as usual.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you really have a file named `myFeatures.json` into a folder named `path` in the current folder where you're trying to submit `curl`, just remove the leading slash from the path.

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/schema/feature-store" --data-binary "@path/myFeatures.json" -H "Content-type:application/json"
```

On the other hand, try to specify the absolute path to your `myFeatures.json`.

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/schema/feature-store" --data-binary "@C:\your\complete\path\myFeatures.json" -H "Content-type:application/json"
```

Comment: freedev your suggestion worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and in my case, it turned out that this was caused by using  `~` in my path.

Answer (score -4):

The simplest solution is to change the extension of a file from ".json" to ".txt".